# What's wrong with this 2D array initializing code?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to take the positions of the cells of a game level and map them to a 2D array. I want to do this so I can make each ground cell (and NOT background cell) collidable with my player character.

Below is the current code that someone created for me:

```
        int tileSize = 20;
        int screenSizeInTiles = 30;

        // initializing multidimensional array of points
        var tilePositions = new System.Drawing.Point[screenSizeInTiles, screenSizeInTiles];

        for (int x = 0; x < screenSizeInTiles; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < screenSizeInTiles; y++)
            {
                tilePositions[x, y] = new System.Drawing.Point(x * tileSize, y * tileSize);

            }
        }
```

It can be found here: [How can I use a jagged array to record the x and y axes of these tiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853166/how-can-i-use-a-jagged-array-to-record-the-x-and-y-axes-of-these-tiles)
along with a better description of what I'm trying to do.

So, when I run this code, I get an empty array in tilePositions. Well, the x, and y values are there, but the values are all 0. The values should be the position data for the cells.

Here is what the tilesPosition array looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/35SH7.jpg

I'm still working on the collision code though... I need this to work before I can figure that part out.

Thank you all incredibly much, you have been so helpful! I am still a beginner, but am working around the clock to make myself a better programmer.

Comment: What's the problem? Your title says "what's wrong" but you've not included any details about what's not working.

Comment: Its not jagged. Was there a specific question?

Comment: Please check the link I included. And sorry, I need sleep... Let me edit my question.

Comment: Edited my question to explain the problem. Sorry guys, I'm not thinking straight it seems...

Comment: At what point in time do you check the value of the `tilePositions` array?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I figured out I put a couple things in the wrong places. I put something in Update() when it should have been in LoadContent(), because it should've been called only once, or so I currently believe. I asked you a question on my old post, as I am having problems with the accessor again.

Answer (score 0):

if you did

```
        int tileSize = 20;
        int screenSizeInTiles = 30;

        // initializing jagged array of points
        var tilePositions = new Point[screenSizeInTiles][screenSizeInTiles];

        for (int x = 0; x < screenSizeInTiles; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < screenSizeInTiles; y++)
            {
                tilePositions[x][y] = new Point(x * tileSize, y * tileSize);
            }
        }
```

it would be jagged (an array of arrays.)

Comment: We found out in my other question that a 2D array is what I need, not a jagged array. The question is misleading.